# Minifying CSS files appends characters to the style classes

Tags: css, sass, minify, wro4j

I have a SCSS file with a few styleclasses like:

```
 #defaultOverview_data.ui-datatable {
            min-height: 14px;
            padding-top: 6px;
            margin-left:21px;
            font-family:Arial;
    }
```

I minify the SCSS file using wro4j, but in the minified CSS file, the style class name is changed to

```
#00defaultOverview_data.ui-datatable {
            min-height: 14px;
            padding-top: 6px;
            margin-left:21px;
            font-family:Arial;
    }
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Could the `#` in the class name `#defaultOverview_data` be the problem? `#` is usually used in CSS to select an element with the specific ID; but it seems like here you're using it like a class name.

Comment: No.. i want to add the styles to that particular id alone..

Comment: In that case, correct me if I'm wrong, but you shouldn't need the `.` there.  So it should just be `#defaultOverview_data.ui-datatable`

Comment: Okay.. removed the dot.. still the same

Comment: What are the configured processors used for css minimization? It looks like a bug....

Comment: I use wro4j for minifying the files. I have also noticed that for some style classes, alphabets are being appended like  eg: .account {....} in scss, when minified turns to .aaacccount{....} in minified file.